# Routing traffic to PODS with a specific label

Tags: kubernetes, routes, envoyproxy

I would like to deploy a RESTService in kubernetes behind a gateway and a service discovery. There is a moment where I will have my RestService version 1 and my RestService version 2.

Both will have the exact same URLs, but I might deploy them in pods where I label the version. When I make a call to the RESTService I would like to add something in the HTTP header indicating that I want to use my V2.

Is there any way I can route the traffic properly to the set of pods? (I'm not sure if using label is the right way). I also have to keep in mind that in the future I will have a V3 with new services and my urls will change, it cannot be something configured statically. I will also have serviceA with v1
and servicesB with v3. Both behind the same service discovery, both must be routed properly using the header parameter (or similar).

I'm not sure if Envoy is the right component for this, or is there anything else? and I'm not sure in which moment I should place this component. 
I'm missing something, I'm still quite confused with kubernetes. Does anybody have and example from something similar?

Comment: is there any problem in managing different deployment files for these two and corresponding services too, you can actually make the use of re-write target kind of annotations  to use same URL for routing traffic to respective backend services

Comment: This sounds like the [Istio sample application](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/) in many ways, though you should evaluate the range of service meshes and their capabilities and requirements before diving in.  Since you will very routinely have multiple versions of the service running, general best practice is to try to ensure the `/v1` API path is forwards- and backwards-compatible between builds and not to try to use some side path to also influence request routing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Service takes a label selector, which you can use if you set labels based on your versions. Most Ingress Controllers or other proxies than use a Service (or rather then Endpoints it manages) to pick the backend instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have **two** `Deployment`, with different labels, e.g.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-service-v1
  labels:
    app: rest-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-service
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-service
        version: v1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-service-v3
  labels:
    app: rest-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-service
      version: v3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-service
        version: v3
```

Then you create an `Service` for each:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-service-v1
spec:
  selector:
    app: rest-service
    version: v1

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-service-v3
spec:
  selector:
    app: rest-service
    version: v3
```

and finally an `Ingress` object. However, the default Ingress can only route by *path*. You may find a 3rd party Ingress Controller that can route by *Header Value*

```
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: rest-service-v1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /v3/*
        backend:
          serviceName: rest-service-v3
          servicePort: 8080
```